# unable to locate resource-ref name * in the deployment descriptor/annotation. META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, jndi, ibm-rad

I am using Rational Application Developer (RAD) v8.0.4.3 and have come across this problem whilst trying to republish my application to Websphere v8.0.0.7.

The console takes a very long time to determine that it cannot find the resource-ref declared in the deployment descriptor/annotation in the `META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml`. However, for each reference it says it cannot find, I have triple checked each class and can see the correct `@Resource(name = "jdbc/SomethingDS", type = javax.sql.DataSource.class)` above it.

an example reference that gives the title message in the `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` (*note: not the *-ext.xml*) is:

```
<message-driven name="SomeMDB">
        ...
        <resource-ref name="jdbc/SomethingDS"
            binding-name="jdbc/TheServerDAO" />
        ...
</message-driven>
```

and in the `ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml`

```
<message-driven name="SomeMDB">
    <resource-ref name="jdbc/SomethingDS" isolation-level="..."/>
</message-driven>
```

Each time I republish a change it hangs on each reference lookup for around 2 minutes then finally prints out the title line:

```
[4/04/14 13:14:44:612 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 8, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:14:44:613 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 11, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:14:44:614 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 14, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:14:44:615 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 17, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:14:44:616 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 20, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:14:44:617 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 24, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:15:14:993 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 9, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:15:14:993 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 12, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:15:14:994 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 15, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:15:14:995 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 18, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:15:14:995 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 21, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:15:14:996 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 24, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:15:14:997 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 27, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:15:14:997 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annotation.  META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml: line 30, column 87.
[4/04/14 13:15:14:998 EST] 0000006e commonext     W com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.ejbext.serialization.EjbextSAXXMLHandler setAttribValue Unable to locate resource-ref name "jdbc/SomethingDS" in the deployment descriptor/annota
```

To make matters worse, Sometimes the ear application decides to restart and the process begins again.

This problem causes up to 30 minutes delay for every. single. republish. so any help would be exponentially appreciated.

Comment: Does the deployment eventually complete successfully despite the warnings?  If yes, does the isolation-level extension work at runtime?  You mention both annotations and XML; are you using both to define the resources?  If you're using annotation only, which classes are you annotating?  You must annotate an EE injection-capable class.

Comment: @bkail: The deployment completes successfully eventually, the isolation does work at runtime (it was a solution to a transaction problem we were having), I only use annotations to define the resources, The classes I am annotation are either EJBs or MDBs.

Comment: Interesting, I suppose the warnings are harmless then. I'm still not sure what's causing the slowness. I guess I'd recommend opening a PMR with IBM...